# Change display of unformatted mail in GMail

Tags: gmail

When receiving mail in GMail, I can get unformatted and formatted mail. The unformatted mail often relies on spaces and letters being the same size. However, GMail shows them in the proportional sans typeface, which screws up the formatting.

How do I change the default display font of unformatted e-mails in GMail?

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gamfbnidfgeeahogblblgafgpdhdkmib

Comment: Also if this is *your* extension can you make that clear in the answer.